# Trying to programatically click a button on a web page with cefsharp

Tags: javascript, html, cefsharp

I'm using cefsharp and vb.net to put some code together to move to the next page of this site:

[https://www.recommendedagencies.com/search#{}](https://www.recommendedagencies.com/search#%7B%7D)

The idea is to read the list of company names on each page and store to a csv file. This part I can do.

The problem I have is that I can't find the name of the 'Next' button - presumably if I had that I could execute some javascript on the browser to press the button.

I've inspected the page in Firefox, but can't see any name I can use - I'm not really familiar enough with html/page design to know why not or how it works.

Could anyone tell me a good method to get button names from a web page? - I've done some searching and even asked a similar question myself before, but I can't find anything which helps, given my patchy knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide a sample of the html.

Answer (score 1):

1. Inspect the DOM for the 'Next' button.
2. Look for id's or classes that you can use to identify it.
3. use `document.querySelector()` to find the element by the css selector
4. call the `element.click()` function to programatically press next

```js
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.sp-pages-nav_next')

nextButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log('something clicked next')
})

nextButton.click()
```

```html
<div class="sp-pages-nav sp-pages-nav_next" data-reactid=".1.3.4.1">Next</div>
```

In the above snippet on load you can see the code `nextButton.click()` invokes the console log. You can click the word `Next` manually to the same effect.

in cefsharp perhaps something like:

```
browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("(function(){ document.querySelector('.sp-pages-nav_next').click(); })();");
```

A very similar example can be found here :

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net

```cs
// When executing multiple statements, group them together in an IIFE
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE
// For Google.com pre-populate the search text box and click the search button
browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("(function(){ document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = 'CefSharp Was Here!'; document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].click(); })();");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply - this is really useful. I'll work through it and see how I get on.

Comment: If it ends up answering your question I'd be grateful if you accept the answer <3